# Get null from POST

Tags: php, wpdb

I have problem with my code. I don't know why all my $_Post have null at the end.This is my code:

```
    function ow_display_user() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');

    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT adres FROM wp_ow_adres;");
    ?>
<h2>Odczyt wodomierzy</h2>
<form method="post" action="">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th><label for="Adres">Adres zamieszkania</label></th>
                <td><select id="adres" name="adres">
                        <option value="">Wybierz swój adres</option>
                        <?php 
                        foreach ( $results as $result ) {
        echo '<option>'.$result->adres.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Wybierz" />
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<?php 
$adres = $_POST["adres"];
global $wpdb;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $spr_liczbe_wodo = $wpdb->get_var("select liczba_wodomierzy from wp_ow_adres where adres='$adres'");
        switch ($spr_liczbe_wodo) {
            case 1:
                ?>
<form name="adres_form" method="post" action="">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Adres zamieszkania:</td>
                <td><?php echo $adres;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Stan wodomierza:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="stan_wodomierza" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data odczytu:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="data_odczytu" id="datepicker" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Kod lokalu:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="kod_lokalu" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Zapisz" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<?php 
break;
case 2:
    ?>
<form name="adres_form" method="post" action="">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Adres zamieszkania:</td>
                <td><?php echo $adres;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Woda ciepła:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="woda_ciepla" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Woda zimna:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="woda_zimna" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data odczytu:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="data_odczytu" id="datepicker" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Kod lokalu:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="kod_lokalu" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Zapisz" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
break;
case 4:
    ?>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Adres zamieszkania:</td>
                <td><?php echo $adres;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Woda ciepła (kuchnia):</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="woda_ciepla_kuchnia" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Woda ciepła (łazienka):</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="woda_ciepla_lazienka" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Woda zimna (kuchnia):</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="woda_zimna_kuchnia" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Woda zimna (łazienka):</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="woda_zimna_lazienka" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data odczytu:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="data_odczytu" id="datepicker" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Kod lokalu:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="kod_lokalu" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Zapisz" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    global $wpdb;
    $kod_lokalu = $_POST['kod_lokalu'];
    $spr_kod_lokalu = $wpdb->get_var("select kod_lokalu from wp_ow_adres where adres='. $adres .'");
    if ($spr_kod_lokalu == $kod_lokalu) {
            $kod_lokalu = $_POST['data_odczytu'];
            $woda_ciepla_kuchnia = $_POST['woda_ciepla_kuchnia'];
            $woda_ciepla_lazienka = $_POST['woda_ciepla_lazienka'];
            $woda_zimna_kuchnia = $_POST['woda_zimna_kuchnia'];
            $woda_zimna_lazienka = $_POST['woda_zimna_lazienka'];
            $data_odczytu = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';

            $data = array(
                    'id' => '',
                    'adres' => $adres,
                    'data_odczytu' => $data_odczytu,
                    'woda_ciepla_kuchnia' => $woda_ciepla_kuchnia,
                    'woda_ciepla_lazienka' => $woda_ciepla_lazienka,
                    'woda_zimna_kuchnia' => $woda_zimna_kuchnia,
                    'woda_zimna_lazienka' => $woda_zimna_lazienka,
            );

            $wpdb->insert(`wp_ow_odczyty`, $data);
    }
}
break;
}

    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that `$_POST['submit']` is set does not mean that the other `$_POST` keys are. Have you checked them all?

Comment: @s_ha_dum what do you mean ? and other variable to 'isset' ?

Comment: You check for `$_POST['submit']` but you actually use `$_POST['woda_ciepla_kuchnia']` and `$_POST['kod']`. That `$_POST['submit']` is set does not guarantee that the other two are set, much less set correctly.

Comment: Okey I get it. But I input all that fields and I have null. If I change $woda_ciepla_kuchnia = $_POST['woda_ciepla_kuchnia']; to $woda_ciepla_kuchnia = 1; it's works.

Comment: But did you verify that the form is sending the fields correctly? Just `var_dump($_POST);` on the page and look.

Comment: array(7) { ["woda_ciepla_kuchnia"]=> string(3) "101" ["woda_ciepla_lazienka"]=> string(3) "102" ["woda_zimna_kuchnia"]=> string(3) "103" ["woda_zimna_lazienka"]=> string(3) "104" ["data_odczytu"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["kod_lokalu"]=> string(2) "33" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Zapisz" }

Comment: There is no `$_POST['kod']`, meaning your `get_var` query will fail.

Comment: I edit my code above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12193/discussion-between-s-ha-dum-and-przemyslaw-suszek)

Answer (score 0):

Please show Your html form code.

Also i think you have an error in $wpdb->insert statment.
Should be:

```
$wpdb->insert(wp_ow_odczyty, array($data));
```

Comment: If I input number or string into a variable I have insert into db.

Comment: This code is incorrect. It throws an "undefined constant `Notice` and also creates a multidimensional array which triggers a `Warning` and causes a database error and `$wpdb->insert` does not expect a nested array.

Comment: When I move code from case 4 (switch) above it's works. Why ?